# How were Feruchemists not affected by Ruin on account of the earrings they wore?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn

As noted many times in the Mistborn trilogy (I can't remember any exact text), Feruchemists used to keep Metalminds on their bodies - including **earrings** - to store Feruchemical attributes. It was later revealed that Ruin was able to control any being who's body was pierced with metal which means he should also be able to affect anyone with earring Metalminds (example: Vin herself was manipulated through her earring). How were the Feruchemists not affected by Ruin?

Comment: [It had to be hemalurgically charged.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/169649/does-metal-have-to-be-hemalurgically-charged-for-ruin-to-control-someone?rq=1)